# Use Session with Silex and cUrl

Tags: php, session, curl, sessionid, silex

I'm making an application and I need to authenticate users with a POST cUrl call:

```
$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider());

$app['debug'] = true;

$app->post('/api/auth/login', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    if ($request->get('username') === 'admin' && $request->get('password') === 'admin') {
        return $app->json(array('sessionId' => $app['session']->getId()));
    } else {
        $error = array('message' => 'Authentication failed');
        return $app->json($error, 404);
    }
});
```

when I use:

```
curl -X POST -d username=admin -d password=admin http://app.local/api/auth/login
```

every time my application returns me a different session identifier!

Comment: Well duh... it will only send the same identifier if YOU remember it... Specify `--cookie-jar path-to-cookie-storage --cookie path-to-cookie-storage` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP Code:

```
<?php

    require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

    $app = new Silex\Application();
    $app['debug'] = true;

    $app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider());

    $app->before(function ($request) {
        $request->getSession()->start();
    });

    $app->post('/api/auth/login', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
        if ($request->get('username') === 'admin' && $request->get('password') === 'admin') {
            return $app->json(array('sessionId' => $app['session']->getId()));
        } else {
            $error = array('message' => 'Authentication failed');
            return $app->json($error, 404);
        }
    });

    $app->run();

?>
```

Curl command:

```
curl -X POST -d username=admin -d password=admin http://app.local/api/auth/login --cookie-jar ./cookie --cookie ./cookie
```

The above command will write a "cookie" file in the current working directory. Please check that the directory is writable or the user has the correct permissions.